# How to combinate the Reactor operation that simplify the code struct which like if or else?

Tags: project-reactor

##### Summary

I am learning about  the reactive programming  framework that  `Reactor`.  I had read the offical operation document with a simple cogition and when i try to do some  practices , i meet the confuse that how to simplify the  `if-else` . In  my mind , it is very cool that all function could combinate with each other and you just  separate function with dot.

##### Main Question

- How to simplify `if-else` with `Reactor operation`
- Is there some other advanced features or usages in `Reactor opertion`?

###### How to simplify `if-else` with `Reactor operation`

Here is my code snippet;

```java
accountRepository.findByAccount(accountVo.accountId())
 
                .flatMap(acc -> {
                    if (ObjectUtil.isNull(acc)){
                        return Mono.error(new IllegalAccessException("account not exists"));
                    }else {
                        if (verifyAccount().apply(acc)){
                            return Mono.just(AccountHelper.INSTANCE.buildAccountInfo(acc));
                        }else {
                            return Mono.error( new AccountException("password is invalid"));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is not supported in reactive flows, therefor `ObjectUtil.isNull(acc)` is NOP here. In case no account is found `findByAccount` should return `Mono.empty` and the above code could be refactored into

```
accountRepository.findByAccount(accountVo.accountId())
       .flatMap(acc -> {       
             if (verifyAccount().apply(acc)){
                  return Mono.just(AccountHelper.INSTANCE.buildAccountInfo(acc));
             } else {
                  return Mono.error( new AccountException("password is invalid"));
             }
       })
       .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalAccessException("account not exists")));
```

as an alternative you could use `handle`

```
accountRepository.findByAccount(accountVo.accountId())
        .handle((acc, sink) -> {
            if (verifyAccount().apply(acc)){
                sink.next(AccountHelper.INSTANCE.buildAccountInfo(acc));
            } else {
                sink.error(new AccountException("password is invalid"));
            }
        })
       .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalAccessException("account not exists")));
```

Comment: The operation ```switchIfEmpty``` is provided for the  ```findByAccount```  not ```handle```? I mean that  in Reactor   when  the ```Mono```or ```Flux``` stream which  previous of  ```switchIfEmpty```  is a empty  stream   that will not  run the operation which after ```Mono``` or ```Flux```  , the value will be which provided by  ```switchIfEmpty``` instead of  its  empty or origin value ? Is it right?

Comment: @Peng this is correct. technically empty is a `onComplete` signal that is propagated downstream.